# Software Architecture - Changing variables in global class

Tags: java, software-design

I'm sometimes confused about how to update variables in the "global class". For example, I have the `Software` class which displays a state string wrapped in a UI component, `StateHandler` to update states/status, and `Plugin` class which updates the state when a button is clicked. A Java-like pseudocode may roughly be:

```
class Software{
    JLabel state;
    ...
    void CreateUI(){
        ...
        state = new JLabel(defaultState);
        window.add(state);
    }
}

class StateHandler{
    static String stateString;
    public void updateStateString(){...}
}

class Plugin{
    ...

    JButton button;
    void initButton(){
        button.addListener(new EventListener(){
            //update state here
        });
    }
}
```

If I make the JLabel static in `Software` class, it will update the state across different instances of the software. If I put the JLabel inside `StateHandler`, I can't find a way to initialize and add the component into the UI in `Software` class. `StateHandler.state = new JLabel();` returns an error.

One alternative, of course, is to pass a reference of the software to a `Plugin` instance, then do some `software.updateState();` But that's not very clever.

What is the best practice to do this? Thanks.

Comment: "that's not very clever." Problems caused by global mutable state have wasted more of my life than I care to admit. Sometimes "not very clever" things actually save you work in the long run.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah I know. The way I did this in the past was to pass a reference of the global object to every class in order to update the global state, like `new Plugin(software)`. I just want to know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i got the purpose right, but since Software owns the label, i would suggest it also serves an event method to update it...

So can you get rid of StateHandler altogether? Because then you may encpasulate the handling of the label inside Software.

So in Software, let's say you add the method

```
public static void updateState() {...}
```

Then skip StateHandler altogether, and when you init your button you can take advantage of EventHandler builder in Java (given that updateState() is indeed a method with no parameters) in this case you would do something like this in Plugin:

```
button.addActionListener(
(ActionListener)EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class,  
 softwareInstance, "updateState"));
```

An alternative suggestion based on below comments. Create interfaces to denote plugin types, and allow for the main frame to load it's plugins on init. A short example using some pseudo-like code:

Create interfaces such as:

```
public interface IStatePlugin {
String UpdateState();
JButton GetControl();
}
```

Where GetControl() returns the button. This allows for several state controllers and buttons to be loaded if they are in the plugin list.

Then do something like this in the main frame init (going through a list of found and activated plugins):

```
//Here we would accept a more general interface in reality, such as IPlugin

public static void InitMain(final MainFrame f, final TestPlugin p) {

//Check what plugin we loaded, in reality this would be a list of different types, marked by their marker iface
if(p instanceof IStatePlugin) {
        //It's a state plugin, so hook it up... 
        JButton b = p.GetControl();
        //Assume since it is an IStatePlugin marker, that it has method UpdateState, add the event
       b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                f.lblTest.setText(p.UpdateState());
            }    
        });

        //Add the button    
        f.btnPanel.add(b);
        f.btnPanel.validate();

        //...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I get your solution right. I think this still requires passing a `Software` reference to `Plugin` if the button is initialized inside `Plugin`, right? So Plugin may need to have a constructor `Plugin(Software software)`. I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: Oh. The button is IN the plugin... Well, what if you add a method 

    
    public void RegisterPlugin(Plugin p)

in your Software class? That's how i would do then. So every plugin that loads, has to register with the Software class it needs. In this register method you can then hook it up as above, because you would have the reference to the needed button. 

When i've made plugin systems i have usually gone this route, having a method for a plugin to register itself with the main program, and one to unregister itself.

Comment: Updated my example with an alternative, maybe that approach is better for you?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! SO did not push any notifications to me, weird. Well yeah, the button is in the plugin. It may sound weird but here I just use button as something may trigger a new state. I like the idea to add a register method...I never thought about that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Plugin  class can be defined as inner class for software class and button action it can update corresponding outer instance of software state

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if `Plugin` needs to be outside the software class?

Comment: Can you add then plugin as instance variable in software class and define state as local variable in plugin with get state method.